# Accessing C++ web service in Android application

Tags: java, android, web-services

How can I access Web service which is written in C++ in creating Android App which is being developed in Java. I read some example about using ksoap2. But just wondering that URL and soapAction are enough OR do I need any special access class to cosume the web Service which is written in C++ (using SOAP protocol)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using SOAP protocol it does mot matter which language is written server in when you are implementing client.

Everithing you need is to perpare request, send it to desired url and receive response.

But you can also use web service consumer tier which would encapsulate low-level operations (request generation, http oerations, response parsing, error processing, etc)
And that is much prefferable way :) .